# Implementing Hot key combination (alt + ~) in Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, autohotkey, event-listener

I am working on migrating features of an application in Windows OS to Linux OS. I got hot- keys to work but I want the specific combination "ALT + ~". So here is the code

```
event.isAltDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE
```

But this combination clashes with the Linux in-built hotkey that displays the task manager instead of the Dialog box associated with my application. This dialog box displays if I give any other hot keys combinations like

```
event.isAltDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.J
```

I need some guidance to implement the ALT + ~ hot key without manually asking the users to turn off the hot key from Linux settings.

Thanks

Comment: Which Keyboard layout/language you are using? English, German, etc. There are a lot of Key combinations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Keyboards

Comment: I am using English keyboard layout

Comment: Country? US / Canada / Australia / UK

Comment: English - United States

Comment: If your key combination is already used by the OS, than you probably have a problem. You may try this: `new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN)`